# Как вывести дочерние строки в DataGridView?

Tags: ado.net, datagridview

VisualStudio2017,SQL-Server2014,C#,Windows Forms

В базе данных две таблицы(companies,products), связь один-ко-многим.
При помощи SqlDataAdapter заполнен DataSet. Хочу сделать следующее: при перемещении по записям в гриде-companies, в гриде-products отображались дочерние строки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Создание главного и подчиненного представлений данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y8c0cxey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо, @Alexander, статья помогла, разобрался, все сделал. Есть еще одна штука: шрифт заголовка Grid наследуется от GroupBox. Как можно отключить эту функцию?